# Flutter show Loading Indicator while building Complex Widget

Tags: flutter

I'm beginner at Flutter.

Currently in my app, I'm developing a "**report screen**" which includes complex widget like `Timeseries chart`.

What I'm noticed is that when I go to that "report screen", it takes about 3 seconds to appear this screen on the app. When I experiment by removing `Timeseries chart` widget from the screen, the app is responsive as best and instantly show the screen.

Therefore I would like to move this `Timeseries Chart Widget` building process to asynchronous and show the loading indicator while building the widget. By this way, I think the screen can appears instantly because no heavy widget building process at the start.

I've already tried the following way but no success.

```
// Chart Widget Building Method    
Future<Widget> _buildChart(BuildContext context) async {
        return Card(
          elevation: 3.0,
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 4.0),
          child: Container(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      _buildPeriodicButton(context, '1D'),
                      _buildPeriodicButton(context, '1W'),
                      _buildPeriodicButton(context, '1M'),
                      _buildPeriodicButton(context, '3M'),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0, horizontal: 12.0),
                  child: ReportChart(data: _chartData),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }

// Screen build Method
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: _buildAppBar(context),
      backgroundColor: CustomColors.GreyBackground,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              _buildFilters(context),
              FutureBuilder(
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none &&
                      snapshot.hasData == null) {
                    return Container(
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text("Loading"),
                      ),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return snapshot.data;
                  }
                },
                future: _buildChart(context),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Thanks in advance for suggestions and solutions.

Comment: Could you also share your ReportChart widget and _buildPeriodicButton function

Comment: I'm facing the same issue here. Did you manage to get it done? Thank you

Comment: same issue here @user2565057 did you find a solution

Answer (score -1):

```
FutureBuilder(
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return snapshot.data;
    }

    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Text("Loading"),
      ),
    );
  },
  future: _buildChart(context),
),
```

Comment: I am trying to return a `LisView.builder`  in my case and I am getting back the error `can't assign listview to future<dynamic>` can you help

Comment: @bihireboris can you show your code with dartpad?

Answer (score -2):

I have used the fluttertoast: ^8.0.8 package as shown below. You can set the toast length to a longer duration if needed. FutureBuilder is not useful in the case, where your widget themselves take a long time render. FutureBuilder is useful while fetching the data required for your widgets.

```
@override

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Fluttertoast.showToast(
      msg: 'Loading...'
    );
    //Code for your complex widget here
  }
```